# What is the default keyboard shortcut to go to top of a file in PyCharm on Mac?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

It's pretty much all in the title. I have of course tried with the up arrow and even Caps Lock key on and off, didn't work any time. I am attaching the image of the strange keyboard shortcut symbols... Any ideas?

[image: What does that strange up arrow mean?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's <kbd>Command + PageUp</kbd>.

You can find all standard symbols below:

[image]